# AWS S3 image upload

Tags: swift, xcode, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a piece of code which uploads an image to s3 bucket. The problem is the same piece of code(same keys/configuration) is working in sample code but it's not working in my working project after a **certain git commit**.

Now coming to question:Are there any framework settings? which I can reset or anything else I can try?

Another suspicious I'm noticing is `let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()`
 This line of code is giving me a warning in the code where code is not working `Warning: AWSS3TransferManager is deprecated: Use`AWSS3TransferUtility`for upload and download operations.`

Even after the using AWSS3TransferUtility I'm not able upload to image, Code I'm using is below.

```
let credentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: accessKey, secretKey: secretKey)
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:AWSRegionType.USEast1, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
    let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()!
    uploadRequest.body = localUrl
    uploadRequest.key = imageUrl.lastPathComponent
    uploadRequest.bucket = S3BucketName
    uploadRequest.contentType = "image/jpg"
    uploadRequest.acl = .publicRead
    let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()
    imageRequestGroup.enter()
    loader.Handler.show()
    transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continueWith { [weak self] (task) -> Any? in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            loader.Handler.hide()
            if let error = task.error {
                print("Upload failed with error: (\(error.localizedDescription))")
            }
            if task.result != nil {
                let url = AWSS3.default().configuration.endpoint.url
                let publicURL = url?.appendingPathComponent(uploadRequest.bucket!).appendingPathComponent(uploadRequest.key!)
                if let absoluteString = publicURL?.absoluteString {
                    self?.imageUrlToSend = absoluteString.lastPathComponent
                }
            }
            self?.imageRequestGroup.leave()
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Comment: Add     uploadRequest.contentLength = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:[imageData length]];

Comment: NOPE It didn't work.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Use `S3TransferUtility` instead of the deprecated TransferManager. 
Sample code is available here https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/S3TransferUtility-Sample/Swift